# Iframe moves content down from neighbour element

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm using display: table-* to style a basic structure.

```css
#page {
  display: table;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#events,
#righ_sidebar {
  display: table-cell;
}

#events {
  width: 75%;
}

#righ_sidebar {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="events">
    <h1>Events</h1>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="righ_sidebar">
    <iframe id="up2europe" marginheight="5" marginwidth="5" src="https://www.up2europe.eu/widget/go/181d4bdc08289da3d78b79ee5f9e7e2d"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the iframe from #righ_sidebar it moves down the content from #events. How to use iframe and display table-* together, but correctly aligned?

[image]

Comment: use `display:block` on iframe

Comment: It has no effect.

Comment: Sorry i miss understand what you want. You may archive this by using css3 flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
#page {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#events {
  flex: 3; /* 75% */
}

#righ_sidebar {
  flex: 1; /* 25% */
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="events">
    <h1>Events</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="righ_sidebar">
    <iframe id="up2europe" marginheight="5" marginwidth="5" src="https://www.up2europe.eu/widget/go/181d4bdc08289da3d78b79ee5f9e7e2d"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add style `float:left;` for '#events' and `float:right;` for #righ_sidebar